# Turn off vibration in ion-reorder

Tags: ionic-framework

My device vibrates when I drag list items in `<ion-reorder>` element. Is there any way to turn off that vibration? Element is a component of ionic framework and can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder)

Answer (score 0):

Probably [@capacitor/haptics](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/haptics) is installed.

Just configure it properly or uninstall it:

```
$ npm uninstall @capacitor/haptics
$ ionic cap sync android
```

Comment: There's a lot in that package. Can you tell me what to configure in it?